# Sublime Build System: Place colon between variables

Tags: python, build, sublimetext3

I have a Sublime Text 3 build file that contains

```
"cmd": ["my_build_command", "/${file_path}:${file_base_name}"]
```

If file_path is "/folder/subfolder" and file_base_name is "file_base_name", the command that is being run ends up being

```
my_build_command /folder/subfolder
```

but my intended command to be run is

`my_build_command /folder/subfolder:file_base_name`

I read that the colon can be used to set a default value in case the previous variable is empty, which explains why text at the colon and after it is omitted in the final output.

How do I use a colon in between two variables in my command? I have tried escaping it with '\' but that causes a syntax error.

Comment: Are you sure that's the build that you're using? I can't replicate your example: http://imgur.com/a/0LsMy

Comment: The leading `/` before `${file_path}` is unnecessary - it just results in `my_build_command //folder/subfolder/...` being executed. It won't error, but it's not needed.

Comment: I needed those double forward slashes for my own purposes. It's on purpose.